# Return selected categories only in custom page meta box?

Tags: categories, pages, taxonomy

I have a custom meta box added to the Page edit screen. I also have categories turned on for Pages.

I'm using `get_categories($post->ID);` to retrieve a list of categories, as you would in a page template, but it returns a list of all categories instead of just the ones selected.

Is it possible to only return selected categories?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I was using the wrong function.

Correct function was `get_the_category_by_ID($cat);`